# Finding items in a group [android]

Tags: android

When I click a menu item I want to be able to un-check all other items that are contained in the same group so i can create a radiobutton effect. What object do i need to cast item.getGroupId() to- to be able to get all its siblings and uncheck them? Here is my code

```
    int groupid = item.getGroupId();
     if (item.isChecked() == false) {
        item.setIcon(android.R.drawable.checkbox_off_background);
        item.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        item.setIcon(android.R.drawable.checkbox_off_background);
        item.setChecked(false);
    }
```

Here is my XML general structure

```
<menu>
<group id = "mygroup"
<item/>
</group>
</menu>
```

Thanks a lot. also if anyone knows how to make the icon begin on the right instead of left of each item that would be awesome, thanks im new to android and this would help a lot

Answer (score 0):

In the XML for the menu, set group attribute `android:checkableBehavior` to `single` as described in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#checkable).